# Can't increase the root partition size on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, storage, aws

I am currently using ubuntu 20.04 (AWS Ec2) machine.
My root filesystem has no more space as per the below output

```
sudo df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.6G  7.6G     0 100% /
```

I have increased the Virtual disk volume (EBS Volume) to 10G. Please see the below output

```
lsblk

NAME     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda     202:0    0   10G  0 disk 
├─xvda1  202:1    0  7.9G  0 part /
├─xvda14 202:14   0    4M  0 part 
└─xvda15 202:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
```

Now i have tried to extend the root partition  (/dev/xvda) using `cfdisk` command as shown below.

```
Device                                                Start                         End                     Sectors                     Size Type
>>  /dev/xvda1                                           227328                    16777182                    16549855                     7.9G Linux filesystem                    
    /dev/xvda14                                            2048                       10239                        8192                       4M BIOS boot
    /dev/xvda15                                           10240                      227327                      217088                     106M EFI System
    Free space                                         16777216                    20971486                     4194271                       2G
```

but even after `resize` and `write`, my partition size is not getting modified. I am not using LVM in my system.

please see the output of parted -l command,

```
Model: Xen Virtual Block Device (xvd)
Disk /dev/xvda: 10.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
14      1049kB  5243kB  4194kB                     bios_grub
15      5243kB  116MB   111MB   fat32              boot, esp
 1      116MB   8590MB  8474MB  ext4
```

Does anyone know how i can modify the size of the root partition here?

Comment: Add the output of `parted -l` or `cfdisk -l` to the post please. You can only resize to free space immediately after the partition, but I'd expect increasing the size of an EBS volume to add free space at the end of the disk, so after the `xvda15` volume if it is indeed the last partition.

Comment: Added the output of parted -l command in the question

Comment: One can only change partitions if all partitions on the disk are UNmounted. Normally, I would suggest booting into "Try Ubuntu" mode from your install medium, but that seems impractical on. AWS. Back up your User data, back up your system (everything) and reinstall.

Comment: i just freed up some space and ran growpart command, and i was able to successfully extend the partition size. Later i ran resize2fs command and extended the file system size too. but i still dont understand why i was not able to change the partition size using cfdisk